# mongoose - Issue with single database connection in app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my app.js i open db connection upon server start up once as it's not a good practice to open and close the db connection in every request.

What i have noticed is whenever i trigger a post api call,it's overriding the first document instead of adding new documents to the collection

If i open a collection before api call and close it after the api call then new document gets added to the collection and everything works fine as expected.

Is this an expected behavior?What's the impact if we connect and disconnect db upon every api call?If it's not advisable to open db connection on every request,how do i get new documents added to collection?

controller -

```
var holidaySchema = new holidayModel();
module.exports.createHolidayPackage = function (req, res) {
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        holidayModel.findOne({
            "packageShortName": req.body['packageShortName'], "tourOperator": req.body['tourOperator']
        }, function (err, doc) {
            if (doc != null) {
                logger.warn("Holiday package " + req.body['packageShortName'] + " already exists in database");
                return reject(res.status(409).json({ "Message": "Holiday package " + req.body['packageShortName']  + " already exists in database" }));
            } else {
                counterSchema.getNext('holidayPackageId', collection, function (id) {
                    holidayPackageId = id;
                    resolve(holidayPackageId);
                    console.log("holidayPackageId 1 " + holidayPackageId)
                })
            }
        })
    }).then(function (holidayPackageId) {
        //code

    }).then(function () {

        holidaySchema.save(function (error) {
            if (error) {
                logger.error("Error while inserting record in holiday collection: - " + error.message)
                return res.status(500).json({ "Message": error.message.trim() });
            }
            else {
                return res.json({ "Message": "Data got inserted successfully in holiday collection" });
            }
        })

    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        return res.json({ "Message": err.message });
    });

}
```

Comment: Where does `holidaySchema` come from? It looks like a global(-ish) variable, so it will get overwritten by each request. Aside from that, there are other issues with your code that will cause concurrency problems (for instance, the `counterSchema` setup to get a "next" id has race conditions).

Comment: var holidayModel = mongoose.model('holiday_package');
 var holidaySchema = new holidayModel();I have updated controller code in the question.I am new to nodejs and so far i have developed the code based on the inputs i got from internet.Any help in resolving the issue mentioned in the question and concurrency problem will be really appreciated.

Comment: You're creating the document (`holidaySchema`) _outside_ the request loop, making it a global of sorts. It needs to be created for each request, so inside the `createHolidayPackage` function.

Comment: Yes.That solved my problem.unfortunately i don't see any option to mark it as accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `holidaySchema` document is created outside of the request context, which makes it a sort of global. In other words, it will get re-used for each request, and once a document has been saved to the database once, when you save it again, Mongoose will *update* the existing document in the database, instead of creating a new one.

The solution would be to create the document *inside* the request loop, so in this case, inside the `createHolidayPackage` function:

```
module.exports.createHolidayPackage = function (req, res) {
  var holidaySchema = new holidayModel();
  ...
```